How to get a value from one dataset to fill in the missing values in another dataset
I having a dataset with some incomplete data




start_station_name
start_station_id
start_lat
end_lng




NA
NA
41.9
-87.6


NA
NA
41.9
-87.6


NA
NA
41.9
-87.7


NA
NA
41.9
-87.7


NA
NA
41.9
-87.6


NA
NA
41.9
-87.6


NA
NA
41.9
-87.7


NA
NA
41.9
-87.6


NA
NA
41.9
-87.6


NA
NA
42.0
-87.6




as you can see I have the start_lat and the end_lng but name and id is NA.
I created a data set from some of the complete rows that have the start_station_name, start_station_id, start_lat, and start_lng




start_station_name
start_station_id
start_lat
end_lng




Yates Blvd & 93rd St
20237
41.7
-87.6


Yates Blvd & 75th St
KA1503000024
41.8
-87.6


Woodlawn Ave & Lake Park Ave
KA1503000065
41.8
-87.6


Woodlawn Ave & 75th St
569
41.8
-87.6


Woodlawn Ave & 58th St
22002
41.8
-87.6


Woodlawn Ave & 55th St
TA1307000164
41.8
-87.6


Woodlawn & 103rd
20133
41.7
-87.6


Wood St & Webster Ave
TA1307000138
41.9
-87.7


Wood St & Taylor St (Temp)
13285
41.9
-87.7


Wood St & Milwaukee Ave
13221
41.9
-87.6




The issue that I am having is trying to fill in the missing data with the reference dataset.
Here is what I have right now

#get all bike station data
bike_share_data <- read_csv(cyclistic_file)

# get data regarding each distinct start_station
station_data <- bike_share_data %>% 
  distinct(start_station_name,.keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(start_station_name,start_station_id,start_lat,end_lng)

# Fill in missing values using merge (dplyr) by matching the lat and lng

bike_share_data2 <- bike_share_data %>%
  mutate(start_station_name=ifelse(is.na(start_station_name),(
                                   filter(data=station_data,station_data$start_lat==bike_share_data$start_lat && station_data$start_lng==bike_share_data$start_lng )%>%
                                      select(station_data$start_station_name))
                                   ,
                                   start_station_name)
)

What I was expecting was to get one row from the filtering then getting the start_station_name by using select.
what I got was
Caused by error in station_data$start_lat == bike_share_data$start_lat && station_data$start_lng == bike_share_data$start_lng:
! 'length = 5734381' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

This sounds like a good place to use left_join + coalesce, or more simply rows_patch, where the key columns are start_lat and end_lng.

Hi, welcome to SO, If you want a full answer please provide a Reproducible Example, its easiest if you share your data.frames using dput so other people can copy them easily to test and fix your code, and make sure they are named and that all data needed for your example is given (so no read from a csv)

Using rows_patch, with appropriate arguments and column conversions:
library(dplyr)

rows_patch(
  x=mutate(df, 
           start_station_name=as.character(start_station_name),
           start_station_id=as.character(start_station_id)),
  y=distinct(df_complete, start_lat, end_lng, .keep_all = TRUE), 
  by=c("start_lat", "end_lng"), unmatched = "ignore")


   start_station_name      start_station_id start_lat end_lng
   <chr>                   <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 2 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 3 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 4 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 5 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 6 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 7 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 8 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 9 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
10 NA                      NA                    42     -87.6

The last row remains unpatched since there is no corresponding row in df_complete.

Data:
df <- structure(list(start_station_name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), start_station_id = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), start_lat = c(41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 
41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 41.9, 42), end_lng = c(-87.6, -87.6, -87.7, 
-87.7, -87.6, -87.6, -87.7, -87.6, -87.6, -87.6)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df_complete <- structure(list(start_station_name = c("Yates Blvd & 93rd St", 
"Yates Blvd & 75th St", "Woodlawn Ave & Lake Park Ave", "Woodlawn Ave & 75th St", 
"Woodlawn Ave & 58th St", "Woodlawn Ave & 55th St", "Woodlawn & 103rd", 
"Wood St & Webster Ave", "Wood St & Taylor St (Temp)", "Wood St & Milwaukee Ave"
), start_station_id = c("20237", "KA1503000024", "KA1503000065", 
"569", "22002", "TA1307000164", "20133", "TA1307000138", "13285", 
"13221"), start_lat = c(41.7, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 41.7, 
41.9, 41.9, 41.9), end_lng = c(-87.6, -87.6, -87.6, -87.6, -87.6, 
-87.6, -87.6, -87.7, -87.7, -87.6)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))


base R
You can simply run match like below
df[1:2] <- df_complete[match(
    do.call(paste, df[-(1:2)]),
    do.call(paste, df_complete[-(1:2)])
), 1:2]

such that
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   start_station_name      start_station_id start_lat end_lng
   <chr>                   <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 2 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 3 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 4 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 5 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 6 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 7 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 8 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 9 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
10 NA                      NA                    42     -87.6

dplyr
I think you can use left_join (data borrowed from @Edward)
df %>%
    left_join(df_complete,
        by = join_by(start_lat, end_lng),
        multiple = "first",
        suffix = c(".x", "")
    ) %>%
    select(names(df))

which gives
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   start_station_name      start_station_id start_lat end_lng
   <chr>                   <chr>                <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 2 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 3 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 4 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 5 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 6 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 7 Wood St & Webster Ave   TA1307000138          41.9   -87.7
 8 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
 9 Wood St & Milwaukee Ave 13221                 41.9   -87.6
10 NA                      NA                    42     -87.6

